# How to deal with VECM with a different structural break for each time series?

Tags: categorical-encoding, cointegration, change-point, vector-error-correction-model

I am modelling a VECM with structural breaks. I am following Joyeux (2007) way of doing it with dummy variables, including the different trace and eigenvalue stats for cointegration with structural breaks. I also read Dr. Giles' blog about this. But how should I do it if both time series have different structural breaks? For example, A1 has a break in 2018M1 but A2 has a structural break at 2019M1? How would I include the dummy variables? Should I just use restriction where the dummy variables in AI will not affect A2 or vice versa? If that's the case then how will I do it?